# Android: Trying to compile native code, getting UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-native-interface, androidpdfviewer

I am trying to fork [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) to replace its underlying library from [PdfiumAndroid](https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid) to [android-pdfium](https://%20https://gitlab.com/axet/android-pdfium).

My problem is, when I load AndroidPdfViewer and PdfiumAndroid in Android Studio, I can't get the project to work, even before changing anything.

The problem is PdfiumAndroid has [JNI code](https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid/tree/master/src/main/jni) that define many [previously declared functions](https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shockwave/pdfium/PdfiumCore.java), but the linker can't link the definitions in C++ to the declarations in Java. The error message has two errors:

```
E/barteksc.sample: No implementation found for long com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeOpenDocument(int, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeOpenDocument and Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeOpenDocument__ILjava_lang_String_2)
E/PDFView: load pdf error
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeOpenDocument(int, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeOpenDocument and Java_com_shockwave_pdfium_PdfiumCore_nativeOpenDocument__ILjava_lang_String_2)
        at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeOpenDocument(Native Method)
        at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.newDocument(PdfiumCore.java:135)
```

[Here](https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid/blob/master/build.gradle) is the gradle file. It looks like there is something missing, although these are the original files before any modifications.

I tried to add this to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.shockwave.** { *; }
```

it removed the first error, but the second is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

If anyone is having the same issue, I did the following to solve it:

- Installed android-ndk tools
- Edited Application.mk file to remove mips and mips64 since they are not supported anymore, and updated android version to 19 since it's the minimum right now.
- run ndk-build in the jni folder / directory.

That created what I was said about in my question

> It looks like there is something missing

That created a libs folder that has the necessary definitions for the linker.